# How to render a link in prestashop 1.7 with Apollo page builder

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

Im developing a e-commerce in prestashop and it's using Apollo Page builder to template it.

In the product page (Ap Products Details Builder) i want to add a link to a cms page.

Here's what i've tried:

1. Ap PageBuilder -> Ap Products Details Builder -> detail2556437236 -> Edit

   On the builder, dragged block tpl code inside the template and added:
   `{url entity='cms' id=6 id_lang='1'}`
2. In the file detail2556437236.tpl added:

   ```php
   {url entity='cms' id=10 id_lang=2}
   ```
3. In the file detail2556437236.tpl added:

   ```php
   <a href=""></a>
   ```

On every try, nothing appears in the elements neither errors on console. It seems like it's not even getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i realized that content wasn't appearing because of some weird cache.

Beside that i had something wrong. On tpl code block it still needs to have the anchor tag:

`<a href="{url entity='cms' id=6}">text</a>`

and now it works fine as a charm

But the @KrystianPodemski answer also works, with 1 minus.

If the page is no debug mode, it will show a redirect page instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't use a Smarty template inside editor in Appolo Page Builder, but the best person to answer this is the author of this module.

You can always link like this:

/index.php?controller=cms&id_cms=111